# Akka actor survive restarts?

Tags: java, akka, akka-persistence

I have an issue with akka AbstractPersistentFSM in surviving after restart, if I try to access the already existing actor instance after restart, I get error.
I want to configure the actor to survive restart. please share with me any java samples that can continue working after restarts.

Complete example in this [repository] : 
https://github.com/ihabyousif/akka/tree/Akka/AkkaFSMSample/src/main/java/com/fsm/sample repository!

The issue is when I create actor with

```
ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create("SwitchApp");
    SwitchData switchData = new SwitchData("sample string to test presistance");
String persistenceId = "switch_1111"; 

ActorRef ref = actorSystem.actorOf(SwitchPresistedFsm.props(persistenceId, switchData),persistenceId);
```

and restart the application and run

```
ActorSelection actorSelection = actorSystem.actorSelection("switch_1111");
actorSelection.tell( new SwitchPresistedFsm.InprogressCommand(), null);
```

it will give an error, this means that I lost the data that was in the first actor and didn't survive during restarts.

I need to find the same object with the same data and state after restart, how it can be handled in this simple example.

please feel free to change in the GIT sample.

Comment: Complete sample added [link](https://github.com/ihabyousif/akka/tree/Akka/AkkaFSMSample/src/main/java/com/fsm/sample)  please feel free to change in the sample code